# Why faced with Migrations configuration key "name" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Project has two database mysql and psql with own migration files.
There is faced with problem when execute migration with custom configuration

```
"name": "symfony/framework-bundle",
"version": "5.0.x-dev",
"name": "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle",
"version": "3.1.1",
```

and when I execute
`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=manager_mysql --configuration=./config/migration_conf/doctrine_migrations_mysql.yaml` faced with error

```
  Migrations configuration key "name" does not exist.
```

there is conf what I use

```
name: Doctrine Mysql Migrations
migrations_namespace: MigrationsMysql
table_name: migration_versions
migrations_directory: 'MigrationsMysql'
```

Before it worked. How to correct execute migration with a separate config ?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, conf for migration bundle was changed and looks like that for my goal

`config/migration_conf/doctrine_migrations_mysql.yaml`

```
migrations_paths:
  'MigrationsMysql': '/var/www/symfony/config/migration_conf/MigrationsMysql'
```